# framerate and monitor refresh rate causes lag

Tags: javascript, canvas, frame-rate, timedelta, requestanimationframe

I've been doing some test coding on html5 and canvas for game development, and ran into a bug that I can't get passed by. What happens was when I ran a basic animation loop with requestAnimationFrame, the velocity of the object is updated, the movement is smooth and all, but then I ran the script on a computer with monitor that had a 144Hz refresh rate (from 60Hz to 144Hz), and my dreams just fell into the abyss.

So I started reading up on delta time and how it fixes the issue with fps in games, and it works, but not quite as expected.

```
function update(timestamp = Date.now()){
    if(!previous) previous = timestamp;
    dt = (timestamp - previous) / 1000;
    fps = 1000 / (timestamp - previous);
    previous = timestamp;
...
   window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

I call update with requestAnimationFrame, but it can be done without as well (timestamp = Date.now()), get the correct information fps => 143.78... dt = 0.006978...

```
    this.vx = 2;

...

    this.x += this.vx * dT * fps;
    this.y += this.vy * dT * fps;
    this.vy += gravity;
...
```

Calculations check out for 144 and 60 Hz monitors ( 2 * 0.0069 * 144 = 2.001 and 2 * 0.016 * 60 = 2.001 ), but there is just too much lag when you run it on the 60Hz monitor. The 2px movement just  isn't as smooth as it should be; which brings me to my question, **is there a fix to this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest if you already have a working code made for 60Hz and you want to fix it to work at any framerate is to convert your current absolute values to speed values expressed in *px per ms* (or seconds, doesn't matter).

For instance in your case, you would do

```
const expectedFrameRate = 60;
obj.vx = 2 * (expectedFrameRate / 1000); // px per ms
```

Once you get all these values converted to speed, you just have to multiply it by the elapsed time since last frame:

```
function animate(timestamp) {
  const dt = (timestamp - previous);
  previous = timestamp;
  
  update(dt);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
function update(dt) {
  // ...
  obj.x += obj.vx * dt; // no matter how it long it took
                        // to render the last frame
                        // it will be on the correct position
  // ...
```

Here is a small demo showing how "speed-based" animations can keep their correct position no matter the precision of the timer:

```js
const canvases = document.querySelectorAll("canvas");
canvases.forEach( (c) => c.height = 60);
const expectedFrameRate = 60;

class Obj {
  constructor(canvas, color) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.color = color;
    this.y = 0;
    this.x = 0;
    this.width = 60;
    this.height = 60;
    this.vx = 2;
    this.xPerMs = 2 * (expectedFrameRate / 1000);
  }
  draw() {
    const { ctx, color, x, y, width, height } = this;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
  }
};

// red is simple x += vx
// completely dependent on the framerate
// will be late if switching tab or if the browser can't keep up @60FPS
{
  const canvas = canvases[0];
  const obj = new Obj(canvas, "red");
  const anim = (timestamp) => {
    obj.x = (obj.x + obj.vx) % canvas.width;
    obj.draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  };
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
// green uses speed, inside rAF callback
// smooth and correct
{
  const canvas = canvases[1];
  const obj = new Obj(canvas, "green");
  let previous = document?.timeline?.currentTime || performance.now();
  const anim = (timestamp) => {
    const dt = timestamp - previous;
    previous = timestamp;
    obj.x = (obj.x + obj.xPerMs * dt) % canvas.width;
    obj.draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(anim);
  };
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
// blue uses speed, inside random timeout callback
// expect hiccups, but "correct" overall position
{
  const canvas = canvases[2];
  const obj = new Obj(canvas, "blue");
  let previous = performance.now();
  const anim = () => {
    const timestamp = performance.now();
    const dt = timestamp - previous;
    previous = timestamp;
    obj.x = (obj.x + obj.xPerMs * dt) % canvas.width;
    obj.draw();
    setTimeout(anim, Math.random() * 100);
  };
  setTimeout(anim, Math.random() * 100);
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid; display: block }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, it really cleared up some things on how to go about coding with a constant fps. I'll just need to work on implementing the same system to physics variables that add up to the velocity.